# Make Selenium Firefox Webdriver trust root certificates

Tags: vb.net, selenium, ssl, firefox

I'm creating an instance of Selenium Firefox Webriver with this code:

```
    Dim fxProfile As FirefoxProfile = New FirefoxProfile
    With fxProfile
        .AcceptUntrustedCertificates = True
        .AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer = False
        .DeleteAfterUse = True
    End With
    Dim fxDriver = New FirefoxDriver(fxProfile)
```

I need it to trust these root certificates to normally navigate through a series of *https://* sites:

- http://acraiz.icpbrasil.gov.br/CertificadoACRaiz.crt
- http://acraiz.icpbrasil.gov.br/credenciadas/RAIZ/ICP-Brasil.crt
- http://acraiz.icpbrasil.gov.br/credenciadas/RAIZ/ICP-Brasilv2.crt
- http://acraiz.icpbrasil.gov.br/credenciadas/RAIZ/ICP-Brasilv4.crt
- http://acraiz.icpbrasil.gov.br/credenciadas/RAIZ/ICP-Brasilv5.crt

However, setting `AcceptUntrustedCertificates = True` and `AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer = False` is not making it. I still receive this screen (connection is not safe) wen trying to navigate, for instance, to https://pje.trtsp.jus.br/primeirograu/login.seam:

[image]

**How can I make my "webdriven" Firefox to trust those five root certificates programatically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below step (check screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr2jl.png) as per step)

1. Close all your firefox windows
2. Launch firefox from the command line as cd ‘firefox location’ / firefox.exe -ProfileManager -no-remote
3. Click “Create Profile”
4. Create a name for your new profile(say Selenium)
5. Click “Choose Folder”
6. Pick something easy to find — like “C:\NewFirefoxProfile”
7. Click Finish
8. Now click through and accept all the SSL certificates on the site you need to run Selenium tests on

Then modify this code as per your requirement

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
profile.assume_untrusted_cert_issuer=True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile='C:/NewFirefoxProfile)//as per above example
driver.get('https://your.url/')
```

Comment: Excellent! Just one more question... I must embed that profile folder in my project, and it has 43MB. Is there something I can drop in order to reduce its size? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can't say in this regards bro, better you can create separate question on this so that other can help. I had not embedded profile folder in my project and mostly I use chrome only to run my automation suite.

Comment: You are right. Anyway I tried to remove stuff (basically all subfolders) and it keeps working, which solved most of my problem.